# Add Google Internet site preview text Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am currently working on a website like StackOverflow for mechanics and I want to dynamicly add text to the preview text which is sometimes shown. Here is an image to make it clear because I don't know the explicit name of this so it is possible that this question is a duplicate but I couldn't find anything. Like this example:
[image]
How can I set the content of it with JavaEE?

I am sorry if this is a duplicate but I could not find anything for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve this with plain Java or Java EE. What you see in the screenshot are so-called **rich snippets** from an HTML website. They are part of your HTML markup and get picked up by the Google Crawler.

Check the official Google documentation for more information: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data